# Connection Pool shared across processes?

Tags: apache, sqlalchemy

My web app runs out of connection slots to the database when enough requests occur. This is despite setting it to run what seems to be a conservative size of connection pool, and I have limited the number of processes, threads. Am I correct that the connection pool is shared across threads, but not processes? And what is a good strategy for choosing a good combination of connection pool size, number of processes and threads, whilst avoiding running out of DB connections?

Error I'm seeing:

> OperationalError: (OperationalError) FATAL:  remaining connection
>   slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf:

```
   max_connections = 100
```

app.ini:

```
   sqlalchemy.pool_size = 1
   sqlalchemy.max_overflow = 5
```

Apache config:

```
   WSGIDaemonProcess test1 processes=5 threads=10 maximum-requests=10000
   WSGIProcessGroup test1
```

Looking at the processes:
$ ps aux |grep postgres |wc
This can increase to 102 under a reasonable load and stay there, despite many connections being idle, and errors come in.

Comment: 100 connections is a huge number.   depending on how you constructed your application, it may be holding onto connections unnecessarily.  if this is a web application, there should be one connection per web request, returned to the pool when the request completes.   The pool is local to one process yes, so if you have a limit of 5 connections per pool, but then 20 forks, you can get to 100.   Try limiting the number of processes total too.

Comment: Many thanks, zzzeek - this is most helpful